# MySQL simple query with int index is slow

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

This simple query:

```
SELECT trip_id from stop_times WHERE stop_id = 345
```

Takes about 80ms, which is way too much time considering I'm iterating through ~10k rows. My `stop_times` table has about 3.5M rows, and there's an index on `stop_id`. Any lead on what's going on here and what might speed it up?

`EXPLAIN [query]` output:

```
id: 1   
select_type: SIMPLE
possible_keys: index_stop_times_on_stop_id
key: index_stop_times_on_stop_id
key_len: 5
ref: const
rows: 474
Extra: Using where
```

Comment: could you please run `EXPLAIN SELECT trip_id from stop_times WHERE stop_id = 345` and post the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `trip_id` to the index on `stop_id`. This way your query will have a covering index and don't do a lookup. Also, check execution plan (`EXPLAIN [your query]`). If the index is not selective enough, it won't be used.

Comment: How do I know if the index is getting used from these explain results? http://cl.ly/ChSQ

Comment: If it's used you will see `using index`, and also index name in `possible keys`(`used keys`) columns (sorry, don't remember exact column names in `explain` output)

Comment: So from the looks of it my `stop_id` index isn't getting used? Why not?

Comment: It's used (`using where` in extra - it means the index is being used to perform lookups of key values - from  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)